# React - Pass props to children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to do a conditional statement. However, I am having difficulty passing through the props

```
const App = ({children, onConfirm}) => {
{modalActive && renderModal(() => setModalActive(false), () => { onConfirmAbort(); setModalActive(false); })}

 if (this.props.Enabled("True")) {
    return (
        <h1>hello world </h1>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div>
        {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

This will give me the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined.
```

I am not sure how to pass props through when it is a function with children.

Comment: You are using functional component so you can't use "this", instead spread props like ...props and then use props.Enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove "this" and add the "Enabled" to the function's parameter section. The reason behind it is you're not using a class-based component. There is no need to use "this" in this case. You have already declared "children" and "onConfirm" in the same way.

```
const App = ({children, onConfirm, Enabled}) => {
{modalActive && renderModal(() => setModalActive(false), () => { onConfirmAbort(); setModalActive(false); })}

 if (Enabled("True")) {
    return (
        <h1>hello world </h1>
    );
}
return (
    <div>
        {children}
    </div>
);

};
```

Answer (score 1):

By defining you `App` component like this

```
const App = ({children, onConfirm}) => {
    // ...
}
```

You are Destructuring the argument which will by passed to your `Component` as usual this argument is named as `props`. By doing that you haven't no longer access to the `property` named `props` but only to the properties which you took of the property which is destructured in this case props.

And on another hand, as you are defining you component as `Functional component` You don't access properties with the `this` keyword.

So if you want to get access to the `Enable` property you have to get if from props by adding it to the list of properties which you get from arguments props which is been destructured like this

```
const App = ({children, onConfirm, Enabled}) => ...
```

Or by passing avoiding completly destructation and have access to `props` instead like this

```
const App = (props) => ...
```

By using props you'll have to prefix every properties passed to your `Component` with `props` to get access to it. like this

```
props.children, props.onConfirm, props.Enabled(...)
```